# SAS Enterprise Guide: How to query library and export results to CSV

Tags: sas

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but I've searched around and cannot find a clear explanation on this.

I am new to SAS, I am trying to pull out logistic recs, separate by day, and save as date_warehouse#.csv

The data is stored in a library, let's call it 'WH' and referenced table is called 'TX'

This is easy to do in terminal but the outsourced IT guy is stonewalling me about connecting via terminal so I can use PIG/HIVE, so I am being forced to go through SAS.

I import the lib using the command:

```
libname WH_LIB sasioimp dsn="PDB" user="username" Password="PASSWORD" schema="WH";
```

I am able to do a

```
proc sql
     *query here*
quit; run;
```

however these values are being stored then displayed in the UI, I do see an option to then manually export to CSV.

Is there a way I can process skip the display process, and run my query in the back-end to write directly to a CSV file?

I'd like to do something like this pseudo-code in SAS:

```
for warehouse in warehouses:
    for date in dates:
        results=*run query with date and warehouse*
        filename=date+warehouse+".csv"
        write(results, filename)
```

Is there a straightforward example to accomplish this which someone could please share?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use SAS to connect to your Hive DB? I think that's what your company is intending you to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
libname myLib ......;
%let path = C:\users\demo\;

*get list of files in your library;
proc sql;
create table list_dsn as
select memname from sashelp.vtable where libname = "MYLIB";
quit;

*function/macro to export a csv file;
%macro export_csv(dsn=);

proc export out=&dsn datafile="&path.\&dsn.csv" dbms=csv replace;run;

%mend;

*execute macro for each name in the list of files;
data _null_;
set list_dsn;
str = catt('%export_csv(dsn=', memname, ');');
call execute (str);
run;
```

Here's a rough approach. I would not recommend this because you know have to ensure the types for each data set is being properly read into HIVE. SAS provides several methods to use python and connect directly to the SAS data bases using python. Look into saspy and sasswat for examples on how this can be accomplished, especially if you have Viya.

You can then save this as a .sas program and call it from the command line or run it as  a stored process so that it executes by default. This could be simplified into a single step but this is straightforward to follow IMO.